# Lambda Expression With Contains Not Working

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I'm new to Lambda Expressions and I'm having some problems getting the output that I want.  More specifically, I'm having trouble with getting the LINQ contains part of the Lambda Expression correct.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// The following line is what I want for my Final Result
var distinctValues = db.Equipment.Where(m => m.Model != null && m.Model.Contains(SearchTerm)).Select(m => m.Model).Distinct().ToList();

var queryableData = db.Equipment.AsQueryable();

var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Equipment), Column);
var constant = Expression.Constant(null);

var property = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, Column);
var expression1 = Expression.NotEqual(property, constant);
var expression2 = Expression.Equal(property,constant);

Expression callContains = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Contains", new[] { <string> } );

var lambda1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Equipment, bool>>(expression1, parameterExpression);
var lambda2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Equipment, string>>(property, parameterExpression);
var lambda3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Equipment, bool>>(callContains, parameterExpression);
var compiledLambda1 = lambda1.Compile();
var compiledLambda2 = lambda2.Compile();
```

I'm passing in any property and a search term and I want to generate the equivalent of the LINQ Query above as a Lambda Expression that starts with "var distinctValues".  I'm having trouble with the line that starts with "Expression callContains".

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: You really need ot come up with better variables names. In only a week from not seeing this code you'll forget what's going on and those names are completely unhelpful.

Comment: Try LinqKIT (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) (https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit). It will take away most of the pain in generating queries.

Comment: `distinctValues`, `queryableData`, and `expression2` don't seem to ever be used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Xanatos.  With your help I was able to solve my issue.  Here's the final solution that I've come up with.  Just a few minor changes:

```
  // m => 
                var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Equipment), "m");

                // m.Model
                var modelProperty = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, Column);
                // m.Model != null
                var nonNullExpression = Expression.NotEqual(modelProperty, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string)));

                // SearchTerm
                var searchTermConstant = Expression.Constant(SearchTerm);

                // m.Model.Contains(SearchTerm)
                var containsExpression = Expression.Call(modelProperty, "contains", null, searchTermConstant);

                // m.Model != null && m.Model.Contains(SearchTerm)
                var andExpression = Expression.AndAlso(nonNullExpression, containsExpression);

                var lambda1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Equipment, string>>(modelProperty, parameterExpression);
                var lambda2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Equipment, bool>>(andExpression, parameterExpression);

                var compiledLambda1 = lambda1.Compile();
                var compiledLambda2 = lambda2.Compile();

                var distinctValues1 = db.Equipment.Where(compiledLambda2).Select(compiledLambda1).Distinct().ToList();
```

First, I used a different overload for containsExpression.  Second, I wanted the model property as a parameter.  Basically, I wanted to pass in a variable property (Column) and variable searchterm.  That's it.

Answer (score 3):

The `Contains` is `string.Contains`. So, given:

```
static readonly MethodInfo contains = (from x in typeof(string).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                                       where x.Name == nameof(string.Contains) && !x.IsGenericMethod
                                       let pars = x.GetParameters()
                                       where pars.Length == 1 &&
                                           pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(string)
                                       select x).Single();
```

then the `.Where()` expression tree is:

```
// m => 
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Equipment), "m");

// m.Model
var modelProperty = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, nameof(Equipment.Model));
// m.Model != null
var nonNullExpression = Expression.NotEqual(modelProperty, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(string)));

// SearchTerm
var searchTermConstant = Expression.Constant(SearchTerm);

// m.Model.Contains(SearchTerm)
var containsExpression = Expression.Call(modelProperty, contains, searchTermConstant);

// m.Model != null && m.Model.Contains(SearchTerm)
var andExpression = Expression.AndAlso(nonNullExpression, containsExpression);

// m => ...
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Equipment, bool>>(andExpression, parameterExpression);
```